# JS Beautifier Ruins Single Line Code Formatting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, js-beautify

I have this line of code that looks great in a single line:

`ReactDOM.render(<TodoBox data={data} />, document.getElementById('app'));`

But no matter how I change my `.jsbeautifyrc` file in the root of my vscode project, it always ends up like this:

```
ReactDOM.render( < TodoBox data = {
            data
        }
        />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Does anyone know how to rectify this?

Comment: your code is JSX, and beautify does not support JSX yet, for me i always keep my JSX code away from formatting

Comment: Oh I see, that's kind of annoying. Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: Is it possible to format everything around the JSX and leave the JSX portion untouched?

Comment: sure VS Code can format the selected block of code, that is way we'll do by hand

Comment: I'll give that a go :)

Comment: @raksaeng js-beutify has supported jsx for quite some time.  The setting just needs to be enabled.

Comment: Which setting is that, @BitwiseMan?